# SwitchIfEmpty not executing maybesource inside

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I have some methods

```
Maybe<Foo> getLocalFoo()
Single<List<Foo>> getFooFromInternet()
```

And want to check local item and if it's empty then fetch that item from network for example.

```
storage
            .getLocalFoo()
            .switchIfEmpty { network.getFooFromInternet().map { it[0] }.toMaybe() }
            .subscribe({}, {})
```

But seens that code doesn't execute *network.getBarcodeTemplates()* this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `(` instead of `{` in the `switchIfEmpty` line:

```
.switchIfEmpty ( network.getFooFromInternet().map { it[0] }.toMaybe() )
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you. And maybe if you will have free time you can check my new problem with andThen
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834989/andthen-executes-before-completable-finished