# AndThen executes before completable finished

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

Let's take two methods written with Rx:

```
Maybe<Foo> getFooFromLocal
Single<Foo> getFooFromNetwork
```

I want to write a chain when we check our local storage for *Foo*. If we don't have any *Foo* we should get it from the network then save it to the local storage and again get it from local storage and pass it to our subscriber.

```
storage
            .getFooFromLocal()
            .switchIfEmpty(network.getFooFromNetwork().map { it[0] }
                    .flatMapCompletable { storage.saveFoo(it) }
                    .andThen(storage.getFooFromLocal()))
                    .subscriber(/**/)
```

The problem is that `andThen` part completes before completable passed into `flatMapCompletable`. I found out that I can get rid of this problem if I wrap into `Maybe.defer{}`. But according to the documentation of `andThen`
it

> Returns a `Maybe` which will subscribe to this Completable.

And maybe is already

> Represents a **deferred** computation and emission of a maybe value or exception

So the question is why my `andThen` part run before completable finished. And what is the best and elegant way to write such chains.

Calls log :

```
06:05:58.803 getFooFromLocal
06:05:58.804 getFooFromLocal
06:05:58.804 getFooFromNetwork
06:05:59.963 saveFoo
```

Comment: Your `storage.getFooFromLocal()` is probably implemented via `Maybe.just(cachedValue)` that executes before any RxJava activity even started.

Comment: GetFooFromLocal implemented via `Maybe.create` 
Here is code of maybe creation
`Maybe.create { s -> if (this != null) s.onSuccess(this); s.onComplete() }`

Comment: `storage.getFooFromLocal()` appears twice in your codebase, why do you think `andThen` is responsible?

Comment: Both getFooFromLocal are triggered before getFooFromNetwork() completes. I added a log to question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public class AndThenTest {

    Integer value;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        getFromLocal()
        .switchIfEmpty(getFromNetwork()
                .flatMapCompletable(v -> saveFoo(v))
                .andThen(getFromLocal()))
        .doOnSuccess(e -> System.out.println("Success: " + e))
        .test()
        .awaitDone(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .assertResult(10);
    }

    Maybe<Integer> getFromLocal() {
        return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("FromLocal called");
            return value;
        });
    }

    Single<Integer> getFromNetwork() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("FromNetwork called");
            return 10;
        }).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                ;
    }

    Completable saveFoo(Integer v) {
        return Completable.fromRunnable(() -> {
            System.out.println("SaveFoo called");
            value = v;
        });
    }
}
```

and prints:

```
FromLocal called
FromNetwork called
SaveFoo called
FromLocal called
Success: 10
```

So my guess is that there is a mistake in one of the methods you are not showing.