# Completable andfThen executes before the operation before it

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

my question is similar to [AndThen executes before completable finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834989/andthen-executes-before-completable-finished)

```
    getLicensePlateObservable(plateNumber)
                .flatMapCompletable {
                    licensePlateId = it.id
                    getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable(licensePlateId)
                }
                .andThen(getNotifyCompletable(email, licensePlateId))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
```

getLicensePlateObservable makes a network request to fetch a LicensePlate.  I expected it to fetch the LicensePlate, store the id into a member var licensePlateId and remove the license plate.  Then the owner with member var email should be notified about the removal.

What actually occurs is getNotifyCompletable is executed before getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable.  Why did this occur and how can I make it run serially?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624863/rxjava-completable-andthen-is-not-executing-serially

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava \`Completable.andThen\` is not executing serially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624863/rxjava-completable-andthen-is-not-executing-serially)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getNotifyCompletable` will be executed before `getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable` but completable inside `getNotifyCompletable` will be executed after `getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable`. You can see it in example:

```
fun main() {
    Completable.fromRunnable {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("finish")
    }
        .andThen(createCompletable("1"))
        .subscribe()
}

fun createCompletable(payload: String): Completable {
    println("create $payload")
    return Completable.fromRunnable {
        println("start $payload")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("end $payload")
    }
}

// will print
// create 1
// finish
// start 1
// end 1
```

so if you want use data from `getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable` in `getNotifyCompletable` you can use solution proposed by Sarath Kn:

```
getLicensePlateObservable(plateNumber)
    .flatMapCompletable {
        licensePlateId = it.id
        getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable(licensePlateId)
    }
    .andThen(Completable.defer { getNotifyCompletable(email, licensePlateId) })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
```

or you can pass `licensePlateId` explicitly without temporary field:

```
getLicensePlateObservable(plateNumber)
    .flatMapSingle {
        getRemoveLicensePlateCompletable(it.id).toSingle { it.id }
    }
    .flatMapCompletable { getNotifyCompletable(email, it) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
```